# Saving UIButton's Background Image After returning back to the view controller in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I have programmed my Button in such a way that, whenever the user taps on the button it assigns a background image to that specific button and the background image on all other buttons become nil. Now, I am struggling on how can I save the background Image of that particular UIButton which the user tapped on before exiting the UICoontroller using User defaults. So, that when the user returns it should display the background image on that particular UIButton. This is the code for the same:-

```
@IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
    
    button1.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    
    button2.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
}

@IBAction func Button2(_ sender: Any) {
    
    button2.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    
    button1.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
}
```

I Would appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with just save the image name in userdefaults ?

Comment: @zeytin Thanks for the reply! I actually save the background image using the following command, but the app crashed:- UserDefaults.standard.set(button1.currentBackgroundImage, forKey: "backgroundImage)

Comment: I think you already you have image in your assets, right ?

Comment: @zeytin Yes! I do.

Comment: @zeytin Could you please let me know how can I save that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is basically *how to save this View Controller's state* and `UserDefaults` indeed can give you what you want.

Your state has 2 parts: one - which button has the image background, two - image name (unless this one is constant).

When View Controller loads you'll want to recreate your state from `UserDefaults`:

1. Get the image name
2. Get which button has the image background
3. Set background for that button <- in order to achieve this you need some kind of deterministic mapping, for example you can use the `tag` field of UIButton.

So, the code pieces:

```
// assign tag values (can be done from Storyboard UI as well)
button1.tag = 1
button2.tag = 2

// saving particular button tag to UserDefaults on tap:
@IBAction func Button1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.tag, forKey: "selected_button_tag")
}

// get "selected_button_tag" on viewDidLoad or smthn:
let tag = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "selected_button_tag")
if tag > 0 {
   // ... find the button with this tag value and set background. 
   // E.g. you can have a dictionary or some other collection with your UIButton objects for easier access.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you just need save the name of the image and use it for button background so you can use such a thing

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set("niceImageFileName", forKey: "zeytin")

let savedName = defaults.string(forKey: "zeytin")

yourButton.setImage(UIImage(named: savedName), for: .normal)
```

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7  this is useful for you ?

Comment: I was actually looking to save the background Image of the UIButton as set by the user before he leaves the view controller and not the name of the UIImage! But, any way I appreciate your help and have given an upvote!